# Como gerar uma seqüência de datas, a partir de datas de início e fim?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Javascript e jQuery têm sido meus algozes. Tenho um campo `hidden` que tem data inicial e data final. Como eu faço via javascript, um for para ir preenchendo uma `TD` com as datas passadas nesse período, da menor (data_inicial) até a maior (data_final)?

Comment: Como estão as datas nesse seu campo hidden? Você provavelmente precisará converter de string pra Date pro poder incrementar as datas no intervalo.

Comment: @Cigano Removi totalmente a referência a asp.net mvc, já que a pergunta no fundo é sobre js/jquery.

Comment: @bfavaretto Ok, tranquilo.

Answer (score 2):

Pode fazer assim:

```
var diaInicial = new Date($('#dataInicial').val()); // usar $('#ID').val() para ir buscar a data ao input
var diaFinal = new Date($('#dataFinal').val());
var novaData = diaInicial;
var tabela = $('#codexpl'); // o ID da sua tabela

if (novaData > diaFinal) { // no caso de as datas estarem trocadas e para evitar um loop infinito
    novaData = diaFinal;
    diaFinal = diaInicial;
}

while (novaData < diaFinal) { // enquanto a data inicial for inferior à final
    novaData = new Date(novaData.getTime() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)); // adicionar 24horas x 60 min x 60seg x 1000 milisegundos por dia

    // formatar a data para o formato aaaa-mm-dd
    dataFormatada = novaData.getFullYear() + '-' + (novaData.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + novaData.getDate(); 

    // adicionar novas linhas à tabela
    tabela.append('<tr><td>' + dataFormatada + '</td></tr>');
}
```

### [Exemplo live](http://jsfiddle.net/HfLBs/)

Answer (score 1):

Pode fazer algo do tipo:

```
data_inicio = new Date('2014, 03, 19');
data_fim = new Date('2014, 04, 13');
achou = false;
i = 0;

while (!achou)
{
    data_tmp = new Date();
    data_tmp.setDate(data_inicio.getDate()+i);
    document.getElementById('datas').innerHTML += data_tmp;
    i++;

    if (data_tmp > data_fim)
    {
        achou = true;
    }
}
```

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/BqM4L/1/